# Dual boot between Windows 7 and Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, uefi, windows-7

My laptop is DELL Inspiron 15R 5520 with Windows7 64 bit installed and i want to install Lubuntu 20.04 on a free space on the same laptop to dual boot between Windows 7 and Lubuntu. What are the side effects and problems/errors that may occur as i dual boot between Windows 7 and Lubuntu 20.04 on this old laptop?

Comment: It's not related to your question, but in case you're not aware of it - I'll provide the manual link https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/  (Chapter 1 is Installation, there is a Manual Partitioning section there too, if you don't want to use *Install alongside*; as always though, backup first).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking sorry.  Side effects are pretty obvious, you have less disk space than a single OS on your system (it's split into two), and the more you RW onto a another OSes partitions the more you risk issues (even if slight; esp. if you forget & hibernate one; then try to write to that hibernated system with the other; the risk depends on user behavior; if you're aware of consequences of actions you'll have no problems). The issues depend on what you do with it, and how you use it, of which we don't know.  If you avoid problematic behavior there will be no issues.

Answer (score 0):

None at all. The installation is automated, so the bootloader settings and such will be configured by themselves. The only thing that will be different in the boot process is an OS picker, where you can choose to boot into Lubuntu or Windows.